# How to update state of a parent while using its another state without causing infinite updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's have components *A* and *B*.

Component *B* only shows the parent's state in `contentForB` in a different format and doesn't manipulate with it. It takes *A*'s state as a prop, applies a function `transform(content)` and shows it, so whenever *A*'s `contentForB` changes, the new content get transformed and updated in *B*.

The problem comes when *A* wants to use *B*'s transformed content and use it somewhere else. I tried to implemented in a standard way, using state-updating function and passed it from *A* to *B* like this:

```
class A extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            contentForB: "",
            transformedContent: ""
        };
        this.updateTransformedContent = this.updateTransformedContent.bind(this);
    }
    
    updateTransformedContent(newContent) {
        this.setState = { transformedContent: newContent };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ...
            <B content={ this.state.contentForB }
               updateTransformedContent={ this.updateTransformedContent } />
            <ComponentUsingTransformedContent transformedContent = { this.state.transformedContent } />
        );
    }
}

class B extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.transform = this.transform.bind(this);
    }
    
    transform(content) {
       let newContent = ...;     ​
       ​this.props.updateTransformedContent(newContent);
       ​return newContent;
   ​}

   ​render() {
       ​<Something value={this.transform(this.props.content)} />
   ​}
}
```

However, when *A*'s state changes, *B* gets reinitialized, it then changes *A*'s state by calling the `updateTransformedContent` which again causes *B* to get reinitialized, thus causing an infinite loop even though the `updateTransformedContent` changes the state object which isn't directly passed into *B*.

Any ideas how to deal with such situation properly?

Comment: why are you calling `this.props.updateTransformedContent` inside `transform`?

Comment: To change the A's transformedContent which is used in other component A renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use componentDidUpdate lifecycle method.

[codesandbox.io]
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-leaf-92nt8?file=/src/App.js:457-475

```
class TestB extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      transformed: ""
    };
    this.transform = this.transform.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.content !== prevProps.content) {
      this.transform(this.props.content);
    }
  }

  transform(content) {
    const transformed = `<h4>${this.props.content}</h4>`;
    this.setState({ transformed: transformed });
    this.props.updateTransformedContent(transformed);
    return transformed;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>B Componenet:</h4>
        <p>{this.state.transformed}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```